# Replace entire expression that contains a specific substring, excluding some strings

Tags: r, gsub

I have a data frame that has a column with a lot of terms like

```
relationships <- c("collaboration", "team", "partner", "sometimes partner", "not collaborative", "disconnected", "connected", "collaborative", "collaborate", "shared", "shared resource")
```

I want to tell R to replace the ENTIRE expression that contains a certain string, but to ignore others.

```
relationships <- gsub(".*(collab|partner|team|shared).*", 
                      "COLLABORATION", relationship, ignore.case=TRUE)
```

This is what I have so far and it works for some of my needs, but

1. I need to exclude certain expressions like `"sometimes partner"` and `"not collaborative"`
2. I need to sometimes select expressions in terms of positive language... If that makes sense... So for example, I want to select expressions that are only the word `"shared"` without selecting expressions where `"shared"` is with another word, like `"shared resources"`.

My data set is very large so I would like to continue to just use root words.

Comment: It is a well-known regex issue, the pattern is always the same: `^(?!.*(EXCLUDE1|EXCLUDE2...)).*(INCLUDE1|INCLUDE2...).*`

Comment: I'm a total noob. :) 
I ran `gsub("^(?!.*(sometimes partner|no collaboration)).*(collab|partner|synerg|symbiotic|team|synerg|parnter|coopera|symbiosis|coordin|allies|convener|together|tgther|communicators|^shared$).*", 
                      "COLLABORATION", df$column, ignore.case=TRUE)`
and came back with errors.
It works without the extra exclusion terms... I don't know how to get it to ignore `"no collaboration"` and other exclusion criteria

Comment: Sure, because you need a PCRE regex, add `perl=TRUE`

Comment: Like I said, NOOB here! THANK YOU SO MUCH! I think that did the trick! I was stuck for quite a while.  I kept trying to get  `grepl` to work for me, but I have quite a few variables that I am trying to convert into other terms.